# Make notification appear without press button and in background

Tags: java, android, push-notification

If I want to make the notification pop up with the aplication in background(2ºplan) and that appear auttomatically

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: i have tried the default notification system but without button and with one if, when if = true execute, but with app suspended doesn't work